# The least quadratic non-residue

Tags: quadratic-residues

For my thesis I need a good bound for the least quadratic non-residue modulo an odd prime $p$, which I can cite as proven.
So I researched a lot and found several papers and bound. As far as I read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Least_quadratic_non-residue), there is the bound
$$
p^{\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\mathrm{e}}}.
$$
This is cited by an article, but when I read the article, it says this is >>the best known estimate<<.
So I get the feeling that this is not proven. Or do I understand this wrong?
[image]

Comment: "best known" means "best proved". See https://campus.lakeforest.edu/trevino/SurveyLeastNonResidue.pdf starting at Theorem 2.6

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, I will have a look at this. I stumbled upon the word "estimate". I am German and maybe I get the term wrong, but "estimate" means, it's only guessed, not proven. Am I wrong? if yes, I would be glad :D

Comment: An estimate can be either conjectured or proved, the word itself is neutral on this matter. You have to view it in context. $3.14159<\pi<3.1416$ are proven estimates for $\pi$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Theorem 5.2 in the paper you linked is exactly what I need. But I realized that it is wrong for $p = 3$, because then the bound is too low. But I want to cite this Theorem. What can I do now?

Comment: I suppose you can cite the theorem and point out that it needs to be amended for $p=3$. Or, you could replace the $1.1$ in that theorem by a larger number that makes the statement true for $p=3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you. I looked up the paper by Trevino that is cited in the paper you linked. There, indeed $p>3$ is mentioned. So I used this instead.

Answer (score -1):

For p = 3 or 5 (mod 8) the lowest non quadratic residue is 2. So you are looking for results where p = 1 or 7 (mod 8). This is a result of Gauss in the Disquisitiones.
Theorem 5.2 you say is all you need, but p = 3 gives too low a bound. 2 is the lowest non residue possible. Thus divide primes into two segments given above and this should solve the problem.